# Why is my Universal App StreamSocket appending 3 null characters?

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, win-universal-app

I am setting up my Universal App for SocketStream, but my Server is receiving 3 null characters on the first transfer. And it is appending 3 null characters on everything else. Here is my code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the click handler for the 'ConnectSocket' button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Object for which the event was generated.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event's parameters.</param>
    private async void ConnectSocket_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // By default 'HostNameForConnect' is disabled and host name validation is not required. When enabling the
        // text box validating the host name is required since it was received from an untrusted source
        // (user input). The host name is validated by catching ArgumentExceptions thrown by the HostName
        // constructor for invalid input.
        try
        {
            hostName = new HostName(HostNameForConnect.Text);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return;
        }

        StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();

        // If necessary, tweak the socket's control options before carrying out the connect operation.
        // Refer to the StreamSocketControl class' MSDN documentation for the full list of control options.
        socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;

        // Save the socket, so subsequent steps can use it.
        CoreApplication.Properties.Add("clientSocket", socket);
        try
        {

            await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, ServiceNameForConnect.Text);

            // Mark the socket as connected. Set the value to null, as we care only about the fact that the 
            // property is set.
            CoreApplication.Properties.Add("connected", null);

            //Do some basic conversations
            DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
            DataReader dr = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
            dr.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            await dr.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text=("Response: " + dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength)+Environment.NewLine);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Response.Text+="Sending USER Guest"+Environment.NewLine;
            dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("USER Guest"));
            dw.WriteString("USER Guest");
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            await dw.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await dr.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text+="Response: " + dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength)+Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Response.Text += "Sending PASS " + Environment.NewLine;
            dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("PASS "));
            dw.WriteString("PASS ");
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            await dw.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await dr.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text += "Response: " + dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength) + Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Response.Text += "Sending PWD" + Environment.NewLine;
            dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("PWD"));
            dw.WriteString("PWD");
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            await dw.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await dr.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text += "Response: " + dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength) + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

My Server receives "\0\0\0". I am never sending a blank message or one with null characters. I don't understand.

What's interesting is if I send USER Guest a second time:

```
            Response.Text+="Sending USER Guest"+Environment.NewLine;
            dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("USER Guest"));
            dw.WriteString("USER Guest");
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            await dw.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await dr.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text+="Response: " + dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength)+Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Response.Text += "Sending USER Guest" + Environment.NewLine;
            dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("USER Guest"));
            dw.WriteString("USER Guest");
            await dw.StoreAsync();
            await dw.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            await dr.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text += "Response: " + dr.ReadString(dr.UnconsumedBufferLength) + Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

The server receives "\0\0\0" THEN "USER Guest\0\0\0". So there are two problems:

Why is it appending 3 null characters and why is the first message sent blank?

UPDATE: I know it is not the server because I use the server with another c# console application. Comparison code is:

```
                Console.WriteLine("Sending Username Command");
                sw.WriteLine("USER Guest");
                sw.Flush();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + sr.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Sending Password Command");
                sw.WriteLine("PASS ");
                sw.Flush();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + sr.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Sending PWD command");
                sw.WriteLine("PWD");
                sw.Flush();
```

Where sw is streamwriter. Here the server receives "USER Guest"

Comment: Is the server code that you've written also? A frequent issue is people new to sockets calling `Read` but not checking the return value. That then leads to them looking at parts of the buffer to which the `Read` call never wrote, which for a new buffer will typically contain `0`s.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have updated :)

Comment: What character encoding are you using?

Comment: @JoePhilllips I have not set a character encoding. Where would that be set at?

Comment: The console code seems to be talking a different protocol. Your original code is prefixing each string by sending a length parameter. Whereas the console code is writing strings followed by newlines. I'm not sure how they can be meaningfully compared.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe I don't understand the Universal app protocol. I thought the Length was only used by my Universal App to set up a buffer length. I assume this because my server is not receiving a length.

Comment: @JoePhilllips the data writer is Utf8 BigEndian by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop doing this:

```
dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("USER Guest"));
dw.WriteString("USER Guest");
```

And start doing this:

```
dw.WriteString("USER Guest\n");
```

At the moment, you're sending a length value, as a uint sent as 4 bytes, and then sending a string. As it happens, the length of the strings you're sending happen to be 10 bytes long. So the first 4 bytes you're sending are 0, 0, 0, 10. As it happens, character code 10 is the same as `\n`, and so it reads as a complete line of text - the same as your console application (which apparently works) does by you calling `WriteLine`.

Comment: @SethKitchen - have you noticed the `\n` in the second example? And read the full explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The null characters were being added because I used

```
dw.WriteUInt32(dw.MeasureString("USER Guest"));
```

Because my text only required 1 byte, the other 3 bytes were taken up by 3 null characters. I changed it to

```
dw.WriteByte((byte)dw.MeasureString("USER Guest"));
```

Now I have 0 null characters appended. I still have a problem because the first communication is just an empty string just instead of 3 null characters.

Comment: No. *Stop* sending the length. Just send strings, but include newline characters, since that's apparently what the receiver expects.